# $X$ is compact if and only if every closed ball in $X$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Prove or disprove:

> $X$ is compact if and only if every closed ball in $X$ is compact.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is not compact..

Comment: If there is a closed ball B that is not compact than there is an open cover of B with no finite subcover. If you add the complement of B to that open cover it is an open cover of X which has no finite subcover. So X is not be compact.So X compact $\implies$ alll closed balls are compact.The converse is not true if X is not bounded as $\mathbb R $ is not compact as Open Ball pointed out. (But if X is bounded, you can cover it in a finite number of closed balls and every open cover will have a finite subcover covering each ball and the union of those finite covers will be finite cover of X)

Comment: @fleablood Slightly more efficient version of the parenthetical comment at the end of your answer: If $X$ is bounded then $X$ **is** a closed ball; just take a ball whose radius exceeds the diameter of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try with the first example we can think of: $\mathbb R$

Comment: So I just say every closed ball in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed and bounded, so it is compact. But $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact?

Comment: $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(n-0.6,n+0.6)$ but if you remove a single set from this cover, the union is not $\Bbb R$ anymore.

Comment: Yeah, exactly right OP